# Handling a powershell error into a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, error-handling

I have powershell code that is similar to this:

```
If ($a -eq $false)
{
    "FALSE"
    exit 5
}
Else
{
    If ($b -eq $false)
    {
        "FALSE"
        exit 5
    }
}
```

I have imported this code into a batch file with the `powershell -Command "& { }"` command and I want my rest batch code to continue only in the case that the powershell command didn't returned an error($a or $b was false).

So far, I tried many things like this but they instantly close my batch file:

```
@echo off
`some batch code here`
powershell -Command "& { }"
echo %errorlevel%
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '5'
{
    `code here`
}
echo ERROR
pause
exit
```

The best way for me to do it, would be if I could exit powershell's "if" block with code "5" for example and put an if statement in batch that checks if the error is 5. The `echo %errorlevel%` prints "5" in that case but seems like the if statement doesn't work.

Comment: in batch, blocks are enclosed in parentheses `()` not in brackets `{}`. Also the opening parenthesis must be in the line where the block begins like in ìf '%errorlevel%' equ '5' (`. See sample answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
`some batch code here`
powershell -Command "& { if $a -eq $false -or $b -eq $false { 'FALSE'; exit 5} }"
echo %errorlevel%
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '5' (
    `code here`
)
echo ERROR
pause
exit
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I finally did something similar to your code by using `EQU` instead of `NEQ`. As I replied to @elzooilogico's answer, the problem was a very simple space.

Comment: I am afraid I am confused by this comment. In your comment at elzooilogico's answer you said that _"the problem was that I didn't have space between the 5 and the ("_, but if you review your question there is not any code with a `5(`, so the problem was _not_ a very simple space. My answer show the right way to write this code: using parentheses in the same line of the `if` (instead of braces) and a space between the `'5'` and the `(`, so I don't understand what you mean with _"After many many tests, finally found out that..."_.

Comment: I completely understand why you were confused. With tests, I mean that I had already tested changing braces to parentheses and also tried many things about handling the errorlevel but almost all the tests were useless because the actual error was just a space. Moreover, I had already found the solution before reading your reply, but I thought that it was the best and more helpful one so I approved it.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell return an Integer when you exit:

```
Exit 0
```

or

```
Exit 25
```

in your batch file run the PowerShell script like this:

```
powershell -Command "& {C:\scripts\myscript.ps1; exit $lastexitcode}"
```

now PowerShell will return the exit code from the script to the calling batch file where you can use it:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: my `echo %errorlevel%` command already prints the errorlevel. Also, I am  not using a seperate .ps1 file.